# Select those entries where the relationship of the columns f1:f2:f3 is roughly number1:number2:number3

Tags: sqlite

I have three columns f1, f2 and f3

```
f1  f2  f3 
1   3   5
5   7   3
...
```

My goal is to select those entries where the relationship of f1:f2:f3 is roughly(+-2) number1:number2:number3

Example:

```
SELECT those rows where the relationship is roughly 5:7:4 -> Result 5 7 3.
```

What does the SELECT command look like?

Comment: What exactly roughly means?  (+-1), (+-2)

Comment: Let's say +2....

Comment: Define roughly, one example could be: select f1,f2,f3 from t where abs(f1-5)+abs(f2-7)+abs(f3-4) < 2, but you need to define what you mean by roughly

Comment: @Lennart see 2nd comment. Also, the numbers are just examples. I realized that you need to at least normalize them using for instance f1 and then apply something as in row1 = 1 3 5, row2 = 1 7/5 3/5 to then compare f2 and f3. But what to do when f1 happens to be 0?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like ...

```
-- test table and data

CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `f1`    INTEGER,
    `f2`    INTEGER,
    `f3`    INTEGER
);


insert into t ( f1, f2, f3 )
values (1,3,5),(5,7,3);

select * from t;

f1  f2  f3
1   3   5
5   7   3
```

Query:

```
   -- roughly 5:7:4 :: +/-1

    select * from t
    where ( 
          ( f1 between 4 and 6 ) 
      and ( f2 between 6 and 8 )
      and ( f3 between 2 and 4 )
    ) ;

    -- result
    f1  f2  f3
    5   7   3
```

[Dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f712e61ff4ae1433cdbf39dc0f346b9b)

```
--  roughly 5:7:4 :: +2

select * from t
where ( 
      ( f1 between 5 and 7 ) 
  and ( f2 between 7 and 9 )
  and ( f3 between 4 and 6 )
) ;

-- no rows returned
```

Comment: The numbers are examples indicated by ...

Comment: @VitalisHommel: ... the test data that you have provided (follow the "Dbfiddle" link to see the complete picture).  Some more details are now added to the answer, too.